# Plotting two vector fields $\vec V_1=-y\hat i+x \hat j$ and $\vec V_1=2\vec V_1$ on the same plot

Tags: plotting, vector

I want to compare how two vector fields $\vec V_1=-y\hat i+x \hat j$ and $\vec V_1=2\vec V_1=2(-y\hat i+x \hat j)$ various concentric circles $x^2+y^2=a^2$ with $a^2=1,2,3$ etc. I can plot them separately. But for comparison, I want to draw them on the same plot. Any idea how to do it neatly?

Comment: How about `StreamPlot[{{-y, x}, {-2 y, 2 x}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", StreamStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> None]`?

Comment: @user64494 Shouldn't the blue arrows be larger than the red arrows? Isn't it possible to use VectorPlot itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

```
a = VectorPlot[{-y, x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},  VectorColorFunction -> None,
VectorStyle -> Blue,  VectorSizes -> {0, 1/2}];
b = VectorPlot[{-2 y, 2 x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},VectorColorFunction -> None, 
VectorStyle -> Red, VectorSizes -> {0, 1}];
Show[{b, a}]
```

[image]